# Java Spring "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a] "

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I try to learn spring.And i got this error on Get method with Postman.
I'm using PostgreSQL, Hibernate and Spring.

My Error is

```
"exception": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException",
"message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
```

My pom.xml postgresql dependency

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My application.properties

```
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

I suppose the cause of this error database connection.But i share my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<User> findAllUser(){
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

**Edit**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String username;

    private String  password;
}
```

And getter&setter method

My UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{


}
```

AddUserRequest

```
 public class AddUserRequest {

    public String username;

    public String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

And last one, My database name is "postgres" ,schema name is "Deneme".

Comment: InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException is a root for many exceptions. You should add more details like what your repository and entity bean (User in this case) look like.

Comment: I added all details.I have no file without added.So what's my wrong? @uday

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception. My guess, that would be trivially confirmed by reading the exception stack trace, is that the problem is that your entity is mapped to a table named "user", but user is a PostgreSQL keyword.

Comment: Thanks! Really my fault is my table name was "User".I changed the name and it work. @JBNizet